# MailChimp + Rails: Send automated email after a day user has been added to the list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, mailchimp

I am using mailchimp-api gem of Rails for subscribing users into a Mailchimp list.
I wanted to send an auto email just a day after a user is subscribed to that particular list.

There are campaigns which we can use but over there we have to manually begin the campaign. In my case I wanted to send email just a day after a user subscribe to the list.

Any solution to it in respect to mailchimp-api gem or w/o the gem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how it would be done only with Mailchimp api as you can't send emails from rails app with mailchimp-api. Any scheduling need to be done, if possible, within Mailchimp service not Rails app.

Solution within the Rails app is to implement transactional email service like Mailgun (https://www.mailgun.com/) or Mandril (http://www.mandrill.com/) or any other mailer service so Rails app can send emails. Generate mailer and all that is needed. For automated scheduling of emails would recommend delayed_job gem (https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) that will run in the background as a deamon. To schedule sending email 24 hours after user register in user registration action call mailer with delayed_job and 24 hours  delay like this:

`Mailer.delay(run_at: 24.hours.from_now).method(param)`

Comment: Thanx @meshin I was looking for something that could be done within Mailchimp

Comment: If rails only can add users to Mailchimp list and Mailchimp doesn't have option for sending automatic scheduled mails then it's impossible be done within Mailchimp. It's not ruby on rails question then